# About the built-in __iter__

Tags: python, built-in

I'm learning python and reading fluent python book!
While following some class implementation, I stopped by this snippet of code:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._components)
```

with `components` being an array of floats, my question is: why calling the `iter()` method on components although it's already an iterable?.

Comment: I am assuming you mean *list* instead of *array*. But anyway, this simply delegates the `__iter__` implementations to whatever `self._components.__iter__` does... `__iter__` should return an *iterator*, not an *iterable*, and that is precisely what `list.__iter__` does.

Comment: Lets say your class was called `MyClass`, by doing this, you can say `for x in MyClass` and each `x` will represent the next element in the iterable (`self._components`). You can rewrite this if you want to devise your own `__iter__` implementation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the answer, it's an array of floats, but why is this assumption?

Comment: @M.Taki_Eddine because it is a common mistake to say array when someone is talking about `list` objects. In any event, what I said applies to `list.__iter__` and `array.array.__iter__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the [documentation doesn't make it very clear](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), it is because `__iter__` **must** (not *should*) return an **iterator**, not an **iterable**:

```
% python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo:
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return []
... 
>>> iter(Foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'
```

Comment: the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types